# Another phrasing for 'to make a mobile phone call'

Tags: phrase-request

What are informal short phrases for 'to make a mobile phone call'?

> I can not call on (from/ by) the mobile right now, because I ran out of money.
>
> I cannot use my mobile because
>
> I cannot ring...

Comment: *"I can't use my cell right now..."*

Comment: But I can use my (smart)phone to listen to FM radio or as an MP3 player or play videos. Doesn't it sound ambiguous that I can't use my cell when I have no money for calling?

Comment: I don't think we have any special phrases for "to make a _mobile_ phone call".  We don't treat mobile phones any differently from any other phones, from a grammar and usage perspective.  If there is something special about the fact that it's a mobile phone, you would just have to explain that in another phrase, like, "I can't call you, because (something about my cell phone)"

Comment: My students often say that they are "out of data" and when they still called one another they would say that they were "out of minutes."

Comment: @stangdon Please comment on the usage of the prepositions _on_, _from_, _by_. What would you never use in this context? Are they all fine?

Comment: @Jason Patterson I can't find the meaning of 'out of data' in the dictionary. Could you elaborate on that? If I still have few minutes, will I say 'I am out of minutes' or 'I am running out of minutes'?

Comment: "Out of data" is the condition of a cell phone plan that has a monthly limit on data transmission.  They might have 2GB of data per month, and when someone wants them to watch a video or download an OS update, they can't do it because they don't want to go over their monthly allotment and get in trouble with their parents.  "Running out of minutes" would be appropriate.

Comment: @Humbulani - It's fine to say "I'm calling you _on_ my cell phone" or "I'm calling you _from_ my cell phone" or maybe "_using_ my cell phone".  I would not say "_By_ my cell phone".  Now that I think about it, cell phones are a little different from land-line phones in one way: I would never say "from my telephone" if it were a land line, but I might say "from my cell phone".

Answer (score 1):

There could be many ways and **one of them** I can think of is...

> I cannot call from my mobile (cell) phone. I'm running (or I ran) out of balance/battery

Note that even if you remove the phrase *'...from my mobile/cell phone...'*, it's okay because ***generally*** you run out of balance/battery on cellphones and not landlines. So, short and sweet could be...

> I cannot call. I'm running (or I ran) out of balance/battery **OR** because balance/battery is getting over (InE).

Comment: Does "balance" mean battery level? I have never heard this in relation to mobile phone.  Or do you use it to mean "remaining minutes" on a minutes-limited plan?

Comment: the battery would run "down" or "out of power", but not "over".  You could have nearly used up your paid-for minutes (paid card) or go "over" your allocation and incur a higher rate (monthly plan).

Comment: @BrianHitchcock In India, battery *can get* [over](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-13973_102-604535/some-problem-on-i9190-battery/) (as in- it's over, finished). True, it's not a preferred choice but you hear this everywhere. I included InE (Indian English) to avoid ambiguity. [Balance *certainly* means talktime](http://www.airtel.in/mobile/prepaid/recharge-online?CIRCLE=17) in case of cellphones at least in India (again!)